# How should `USING start_time::timestamp without time zone` be specified in Flask SQLALchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

My objective was to alter a column's data type from `String` to `DateTime` in Flask using Flask SQLAlchemy.

This is the model in question:

```
class Show(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    venue_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('venues.id'))
    venue_name = db.Column(db.String)
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artists.id'))
    artist_name = db.Column(db.String)
    artist_image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))

    # column at fault 
    start_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=False))
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Show id: {self.id} venue_id: {self.venue_id} artist_id: {self.artist_id} start_time: {self.start_time}>'
```

Running `flask db migrate` works fine and initially generates this migration script:

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '3ac508896870'
down_revision = '90b7c2f14692'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column('shows', 'start_time',
               existing_type=sa.VARCHAR(length=50),
               type_=sa.DateTime(),
               existing_nullable=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.alter_column('shows', 'start_time',
               existing_type=sa.DateTime(timezone=False),
               type_=sa.VARCHAR(length=50),
               existing_nullable=True)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

After running `flask db upgrade`, I get a error message with the following hint at the end:

```
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING start_time::timestamp without time zone".

[SQL: ALTER TABLE shows ALTER COLUMN start_time TYPE TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE ]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

Based on that, I took a look at the SQLAlchemy [docs on the DateTime type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html?highlight=datetime#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime) and believing that the issue was the missing timezone parameter, I added it to the migration script like so:

```
op.alter_column('shows', 'start_time',
           existing_type=sa.VARCHAR(length=50),
           type_=sa.DateTime(timezone=False),
           existing_nullable=True)
```

However, the error persisted. So I'm asking, what is the appropriate way to specify `USING start_time::timestamp without time zone`? Or perhaps the error's hint wasn't the right solution?

I'm new to Flask by the way, so I'm just stumbling my way through docs to figure things out.

**EDIT:** I resolved this issue for myself by completely dropping the existing String type column and replacing it with a new DateTime column. This won't be ideal for all solutions and was only possible because there was no crucial data in the table.

Still looking for less dramatic solutions.